# Is it nesessary to synchronize access to shared memory if one process is read only?

Tags: linux, process, ipc, shared-memory

Having two processes one of which reads and writes data to the shared memory segment and second one only reads(and it's not critical if data changes during reading). Is there any danger if not to use synchronization between them?

Comment: It depends on what you consider "dangerous", and how you assessed that it's not "critical" if the data changed while it was being read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shared Memory when it's for read only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249037/shared-memory-when-its-for-read-only)

Comment: How can it be not critical if data changes during reading? You could get a result that contains part of the old value and part of the new value, which would probably be meaningless.

Comment: But if that really doesn't matter, then you don't need synchronization. The only purpose of synchronization is to prevent that from happening.